# JQuery drop down menu on change show div when certain menu items are selected

Tags: javascript, html, onchange

I am trying to get a Div to show when certain items are selected from a drop down menu. For some reason it is showing when any of the items in the menu are selected and I cant figure out why. Thanks for your help!

```
<select class="selectDesign" id="designOne" name="design1">
<option value="none">None</option>
<option value="ace">Ace</option>
<option value="aerialist">Aerialist</option>
<option value="anthropologie">Anthropologie</option>
<option value="clare">Clare</option>
<option value="darcy">Darcy</option>
<option value="dauphine">Dauphine</option>
<option value="derby">Derby</option>
<option value="signature">Signature</option>
</select>

<div id="showPaints" style="display: none"><p>My Stuff</p></div>
```

javaScript

```
jQuery("#designOne").change(function(){

jQuery("#showPaints").hide("slow");

if (jQuery("#designOne").val() == "signature" , "ace" ) {
    jQuery("#showPaints").show("slow");

}

});
```

Comment: Thanks, I am new so Im going to go through and do this.

Comment: Cool, your previous answerers will appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is.. odd syntax.

```
if (jQuery("#designOne").val() == "signature" , "ace" )
```

Try:

```
var chosenValue = jQuery("#designOne").val();
if (chosenValue == "signature" || chosenValue == "ace" )
```

I think the `, 'ace'` might be getting translated to boolean true therefore the if always gets hit. I might just run a test in jsfiddle.